# Find the max value for Y axis scaling across an arbitrary number of columns referenced indirectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a working multi-line, time-series chart in d3 (processing durations in minutes for various dates).  I have written the path code so that an arbitrary number of columns can be returned in the dataset, resulting in a fewer or greater number of lines being plotted (using indirect references).  I am trying to now scale the Y axis using any of the data values in the data set beyond column 0.  The first column returned is assumed to be the time-scale.

I have this for the scaling line:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Overall; })]);
```

However, I am referencing a specific column that I know has the overall processing duration, so the scaling works, but I don't want to reference the data by name, but rather by position: any columnar data beyond column 0.

I can also indirectly reference this same column with:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d[headers[7]]; })]);
```

What I really would like to do is to not include the overall processing time column at all and do something like this:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d[headers[1]], d[headers[2]], d[headers[3]], d[headers[4]], d[headers[5]], d[headers[6]] ); })])
```

However, I don't want to specify the array indexes, so that an arbitrary number of columns can be evaluated by d3.max().

Any ideas on how to do this?  Maybe some variation of:

```
return for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { aHeaders[i-1] = d[headers[i]]; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the data with `d3.csv` an array property named `columns` is created, which you can use to get all the column names.

For instance:

```js
const csv = `foo,bar,baz,foobar,foobaz
1000,345,54,22,34
25,87,123,43,65
17,98,222,88,76`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

console.log(data.columns)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In your case you don't need the names, but that property is useful to get the number of columns in your CSV. With that in mind, you can use a nested `d3.max`, like this:

```
const max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d3.range(1, data.columns.length, 1).map(function(e) {
    return d[data.columns[e]]
  }))
});
```

Here, `d3.range(1, data.columns.length, 1)` gets all the indices except for the first one (`0`). You can also use it as a constant, so it doesn't need to be calculated for every row.

Here is the demo:

```js
const csv = `foo,bar,baz,foobar,foobaz
1000,345,54,22,34
25,87,123,43,65
17,98,222,88,76`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

const columnIndices = d3.range(1, data.columns.length, 1);

const max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(columnIndices.map(function(e) {
    return d[data.columns[e]]
  }))
});

console.log(max)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the first column is ignored. For other situations, just populate the `columnIndices` array with the indices you want.